# ORM peewee ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'peewee'

Tags: python, visual-studio, orm, python-venv, peewee

In venv, I installed the module using the command pip install peewee (it was written into requirements.txt). I wrote this code for testing and got an error:  line 1, in <module>
from peewee import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'peewee'. How to fix this? Python 3.12.0('venv':venv). I use VSCode

```
from peewee import (
    SqliteDatabase,
    Model,
    PrimaryKeyField,
    CharField,
    FloatField,
    DateField,
    ForeignKeyField,
)

db = SqliteDatabase("database.db")


class BaseModel(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        database = db
        order_by = "id"


class Expense(Model):
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "expense"


class Payment(Model):
    amount = FloatField()
    payment_date = DateField()
    expense_id = ForeignKeyField(Expense)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "payment"


# Connect to the database
db.connect()

# Create tables
db.create_tables([Expense, Payment])
```

I tried reinstalling the module, installing it in other projects in new venvs, restart IDE

Comment: what is the output of running `pip show peewee` in your terminal?

Comment: Name: peewee
Version: 3.17.0
Summary: a little orm
Home-page: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/
Author: Charles Leifer
Author-email: coleifer@gmail.com
License: MIT License
Location: C:\Code\OSPanel\domains\study\venv\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Comment: also in your IDE or REPL, try `import sys; print(sys.path)` and send the output

Comment: Wild guess: you might have multiple versions of Python. You want to be sure that the python in your venv can find peewee

Comment: The global and virtual versions are the same, but the peewee module does not want to work either with the virtual environment activated or without it(((((

Comment: import sys
print(sys.path)      Text in terminal: ['c:\\Code\\OSPanel\\domains\\study', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Do you have another installation of Python besides 3.12?

Comment: No, i don't have another installation of Python besides 3.12 ‍♂️ A very strange situation, this has never happened before where pip modules did not work